# Diango: validate model object's field values against user defined rules before saving/deleting

Tags: django

I need to develop a new feature for an existing project. The feature is to check the validation of model instances' field values according to some admin user defined rules before saving/deleting to/from database. I know django provides a form field validation mechanism in which I can define custom logic, but that's seems not the right way to go because what models and fields that have rules defined on is unpredictable and not all models have it's corresponding form. I think I'd better describe the whole scenario with an example.

There is an admin user defined three rule as following, the rules are stored in database.

```
Rule 1:
    model: Book
    field: author
    operator: is
    values: Shakespeare

Rule 2:
    model: Book
    field: publish_date
    operator: greater than 
    values: 2000-1-1

Rule 3:
    model: Book
    field: publisher.location (Book has a ForeignKey relationship to Publisher)
    operator: not in
    values: U.K.
```

So when an logged in user want to save a Book object authored by other than Shakespeare or the publisher location is in U.K., we shall deny the operation and inform the user he cannot complete the operation because he violate some rules. Also the user might view some books not authored by Shakespeare, but he has no way to delete it.

One option I can think of is to use pre_save on all potential rule constrained models and check if rules exist on the model and then do validation there, but this seems to be too much change to the existing system because we have a lot of models.

I'm wondering if there is any simple way to do this kind of work?

Comment: django guardian (https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian) allows for implementaion of per-object permissions but I'm not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for...

Comment: Thanks, @yuvi. I'm aware of this project. It's more like a fine-grained ACL, but does not provide tools that we can define permission or rules based on attributes.

Comment: Then alternatively, you can register the permission object in your admin site (or rather, create a costume PermissionAdmin class). Would that be of any help?

Comment: Not quite get your idea, what do you mean the permission object? is it the same as the permission rule I described above? If so I think we already have it in admin, the problem is that how to apply them to check the model instances.

Comment: I mean to add this to admin.py: admin.site.register(django.contrib.auth.models.Permission).
Honestly, I'm not sure this would help, but the concept is that you can register anything in the admin site, so my approach to this would be to create some kind of mediatory model "Rule" between permissions and the user model, then register that with the admin site and build a custom form for it that would be easy to use. It's my thinking that that's the direction to go, but I'll admit I never did anything of the sort so I'm not entirley sure what you want to do is even possible